# Wrapping Antd Component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to wrap antd component eg. `Input` into MyInput so I can add support for new pros and classNames, however it stoped working when I put then inside of the `Form`

MyInput.js

```
import { Input } from 'antd';

function MyInput({ className='', ...rest }) {
  const computedClassName = 'my-input '+className;

  return (
    <Input className={computedClassName} {...rest} />
  );
}

MyInput.defaultProps = Input.defaultProps;
MyInput.propTypes = Input.propTypes;
MyInput.Group = Input.Group;
MyInput.Search = Input.Search;
MyInput.TextArea = Input.TextArea;
```

Now if I put `<MyInput />` inside of `<Form/>` it stops working

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/kossel/pen/VMwMxZ?&editors=001)

I tried to debug, looks like the `saveRef` function in rc-form/lib/createBaseForm is receiving null as component argument, so this makes me feel is a ref problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found the answer...

As per [Refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-functional-components) documentation

refs doesnt work on stateless components, change it to class and worked